# How to redirect an IP address to a machine/hostname in an Intranet?

Tags: networking, dns, redirection, domain-name, letsencrypt

I have a couple of intranet applications at home like an NVR server and a Plex Media Server. Each are installed in a FreeNAS jail with corresponding IP addresses like 192.168.0.2 with hostname mynvr and 192.168.0.3 with hostname myplex.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I enter http://192.168.0.2 to access the GUI of my NVR server, I want it to redirect it to http://mynvr.local or something. Reason for this is I'm trying to generate SSL using LetsEncrypt and I believe it doesn't support ip addresses.

Appreaciate any feedback.

Regards,
Allen

Comment: sounds like you need a DNS server for your lan. at least thats how I solved host naming in my personal lan.

Comment: thanks but doesn't a dns server point hostnames to ip addresses? my goal is to make sure my web servers can't be access via http://ip_address. basically i'm trying to avoid unsecured logins to my intranet web application servers via http.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to prevent unsecured logins to intranet sites in your own home? You really don't trust your mom eh?

Comment: to provide some context on NetSrvOps's comment, certificates are there to ensure that you are connecting to the correct server, and that a hacker hasn't dropped a malicious server between you and the real server, so its a man in the middle attack. an adversary would need signifigant access within your lan to do that. alternately, https is designed to protect credentials and traffic between the client and the server. this is also a man in the middle attack, so only people already on your lan would be able to sniff traffic to try to expose credentials and data in transit.

Comment: @NetServOps actually i am using my company laptop in my home network. it automatically connects to their vpn and maybe i'm being paranoid but it probably uses some sort of url sniffing (to check if we are actually using it for work. i've received memo before about downloading a non work-related application :D). anyway, sometimes i logged in to my NVR using this and i'm worried since they have installed a lot of stuff here that detects what we do with it, they might be able to sniff the username/password passed via basic auth.

Comment: @ads Ok if its a work laptop then there is probably nothing you can do. Even if they had split-tunnelling setup on your vpn so you downloaded software outside the VPN, the hardware and OS is still under their control so they would still see that.
If you're concerned whether they could 'sniff' the username/password via basic auth, sure, they could if they wanted to and had the means.
Remember you are using their hardware, EVERYTHING you do is being logged and controlled. If you're that worried about them hacking into your server, then simply don't access your server on their hardware.

Comment: @NetServOps Thanks. Won't argue with you there. But there are cases where it might be convenient to use the work laptop so if there was at least some way I can protect myself from them. I know they don't use keylogger as I think that would be illegal. I think they mostly monitor network traffic. So what I want to know is, can they sniff out username/password via basic auth if I logged in on an https website as compared to logging in to an http site? If https will make it a bit harder for them then I will at least try to secure my intranet sites with https.

Comment: @ads Generally speaking, HTTPS is much more secure than HTTP. However there is a way to decrypt your HTTPS traffic since you're using their hardware/software and VPN. The point is though, it depends on who you work for and how much they decide your activity needs to be monitored.
If you work for the NSA then you can bet if you sneezed, they would know about it. If you work for a teddy bear factory, then they wouldn't have the technical ability or need to monitor your activity to that extent.
So from a technical standpoint, yes its possible. Whether they would do it, is for you to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is via [url rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) at the server, which detects a bad pattern and rewrites the url to a good one, so that the users browser is redirected to the good url, away from the bad one.

That said, since your concern is about http vs https, disable web site bindings for http in your webserver, so users must use https. your server will stop listening on TCP\80.

Make sure the site uses [host headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header) for its bindings. and consider requiring [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), and [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Certificates secure clients from malicious web apps, not the other way around. having a certificate will not affect http traffic, so you need to disable http at the webserver (or rewrite urls, and/or use hsts to auto redirect to https). a certificate is useless without a dns server, which is why I brought it up, so you will need a dns entry for your site that has the same name the user will type into their browser. all a cert will do, is tell you if the name on the cert matches the dns name supplied in the url in the browser.

hope that helps